# Extracting a column from a data frame which is stored in a list. List consists of multiple data frames

Tags: pandas, list, dataframe, indexing, jupyter

I have a list called data which consists of multiple dataframes. data[0], data[1] etc will show the dataframe 1, dataframe 2 etc. All the data frames are different in terms of no.of rows and no.of attributes. I would like to know is there a way we can write data[1][2] to extract dataframe 2 and column 3 name. That is data[i][j] represents (i+1)th data frame and (j+1)th attribute in (i+1)th data frame.

list(data[1].columns.values)
I understand that the above code gives me all the attributes. I'm interested in knowing the indexing using the above-mentioned way - data[i][j].

```
import os
import pandas as pd
path = os.getcwd()
files = os.listdir(path)
files
files_xlxs = [f for f in files if f[-4:] == 'xlsx']
files_xlxs = [f for f in files_xlxs if '$' not in f]
data = [] 
for f in files_xlxs:
    pathFile = path + '\\' + f
    print(pathFile)
    data.append(pd.read_excel(pathFile))
data[1]
```

Data[1][2] should extract the third column name from data frame 2. After compilation, the following error is occurring.

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2656             try:
-> 2657                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2658             except KeyError:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 2

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
----> 1 data[1][2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What pandas is trying to tell you is that you're attempting to access a column named `2` in a data frame that has no column named `2`. You can't access columns in a data frame the same way that you access elements in a list, i.e. by index.

What you can do, though, is to grab the column identifier from a list of the data frame's columns, and then use that to query your data frame. Instead of doing `data[1][2]` you can do `data[1][data[1].columns[2]]`.

Here's a complete example with a list called `data`, containing two data frames, each with two columns:

```
import pandas as pd
data = [
    pd.DataFrame({"number": [1, 2, 3], "age": [10, 20, 30]}, columns=["number", "age"]),
    pd.DataFrame({"value": [4, 5, 6], "bananas": [40, 50, 60]}, columns=["value", "bananas"])
]

# Print the content of each data frame
for df in data:
    print df
```

This prints out the two data frames:

```
   number  age
0       1   10
1       2   20
2       3   30
   value  bananas
0      4       40
1      5       50
2      6       60
```

Then we access and print only the 2nd column of each data frame in the list, which prints the `age` column and `bananas` column, respectively:

```
# Print 2nd column of 1st data frame
print data[0][data[0].columns[1]]

# Print 2nd column of 2nd data frame
print data[1][data[1].columns[1]]
```

Which gives:

```
0    10
1    20
2    30
Name: age, dtype: int64
0    40
1    50
2    60
Name: bananas, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Instead of printing the second column of 1st data frame. I would like to print only the column name i.e., age. Could you please help me with this.

Comment: `print data[0].columns[1]`. `data[0]` is a DataFrame, and DataFrame.columns lists the labels of the columns within it. So `data[0].columns[1]` gives the label for the second column in the first DataFrame